# React - List elements are not animated with AnimatePresence

Tags: reactjs, google-chrome-extension, framer-motion

I'm trying to implement AnimatePresence when one element from the list is removed. I want to fadeout removed element and move the rest of the list to fill the gap but unfortunatelly place after removed element is replaced immediately.
it's simple browser extension to save actual viewed tab.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import "./App.css";
import { style } from "./assets/Styling";
import TabList from "./components/TabList";

function App() {
  const [mySites, setMySites] = useState([]);
  const [inputTitle, setInputTitle] = useState("");
  const [inputComment, setInputComment] = useState("");

  useEffect(() => {
    const storage = chrome?.storage?.local;
    // const storage = chrome?.storage?.local || browser?.storage?.local;

    if (!storage) {
      console.error("WebExtensions storage API not supported");
      return;
    }

    storage.get("mySites", (result) => {
      const sitesFromStorage = result.mySites;
      if (sitesFromStorage) {
        setMySites((prevSites) => [...prevSites, ...sitesFromStorage]);
      }
    });
  }, []);

  const saveTab = () => {
    chrome.tabs.query({ active: true, currentWindow: true }, (tabs) => {
      const newSite = {
        title: inputTitle || tabs[0].title,
        comment: inputComment,
        url: tabs[0].url,
      };

      const updatedSites = [...mySites, newSite];
    setMySites(updatedSites);

    const storage = chrome?.storage?.local || browser?.storage?.local;
    if (storage) {
      storage.set({ mySites: updatedSites });
    }

      setInputTitle("");
      setInputComment("");
    });
  };

  const deleteSite = (index) => {
    const updatedSites = [...mySites];
    updatedSites.splice(index, 1);
  
    setMySites(updatedSites);
  
    const storage = chrome?.storage?.local || browser?.storage?.local;
    if (storage) {
      storage.set({ mySites: updatedSites });
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className={style.bg}>
      <div className={style.container}>
        <div className={style.logo}>
          <p className={style.logoText}>TabMinder</p>
        </div>
        <input
          className={style.input}
          type='text'
          id='input-title'
          placeholder='custom title'
          maxLength='35'
          required
          value={inputTitle}
          onChange={(e) => setInputTitle(e.target.value)}
        />
        <input
          className={style.input}
          id='input-comment'
          placeholder='additional comment'
          maxLength='150'
          value={inputComment}
          onChange={(e) => setInputComment(e.target.value)}
        />

        <button onClick={saveTab} id='save-btn' className={style.savebutton}>
          Add Tab
        </button>

        <ul>
          <TabList mySites={mySites} deleteSite={deleteSite} />
</ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}


export default App;
```

```
import React from "react";
import { motion, AnimatePresence } from "framer-motion";
import { style } from "../assets/Styling";
import TabItem from "./TabItem"

function TabList({ mySites, deleteSite }) {
  return (
    <ul>
      <AnimatePresence mode="sync">
        {mySites.map((site, index) => (
          <TabItem key={index} site={site} index={index} deleteSite={deleteSite} />
        ))}
      </AnimatePresence>
    </ul>
  );
}

export default TabList;
```

```
import {React, useRef} from "react";
import { motion } from "framer-motion";
import { RxCross2 } from "react-icons/rx";
import { style } from "../assets/Styling";

const TabItem = ({ site, index, deleteSite }) => (
  <motion.li
    layout
    key={index}
    initial={{ opacity: 0 }}
    animate={{ opacity: 1 }}
    exit={{ opacity: 0 }}
    transition={{ duration: 0.3 }}
  >
    <div className={style.tabContainer}>
      <div className={style.tabtext}>
        <a target="_blank" href={site.url} className={style.tabTitle}>
          {site.title}
        </a>
        <p className={style.tabComment}>{site.comment}</p>
      </div>
      <div className={style.tabDelete}>
        <button onClick={() => deleteSite(index)}>
          <RxCross2 />
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </motion.li>
);

export default TabItem;
```

I want to animate the rest of the list when one of TabItems is removed.

I've tried gpt solutions, and figure how it works with framer motion documentation with no results.